# Piecewise conversion of an MFC app to Unicode/MBCS

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, mbcs

I have a large MFC application that I am extending to allow for multi-lingual input.  At the moment I need to allow the user to enter Unicode data in edit boxes on a single dialog.

Is there a way to do this without turning UNICODE or MBCS on for the entire application?  I only need a small part of the application converted at the moment.  Is it possible to do this piecewise, and if so, how?

---

Clarification:  I could use ::GetWindowTextW() to get Unicode information out of the window.  I am trying to figure out how to allow the user to enter Unicode text in the window.  Currently, **characters the user types** outside of the windows-1252 codepage show up as '?'.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Why can't you just go full Unicode?

Answer (score 4):

To allow `CEdit` to show Unicode characters you should create it with `CreateWindowW` function. I've just tested it in ANSI MFC program.

```
// allows Unicode characters
CreateWindowW( L"EDIT", L"", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 50, 20, GetSafeHwnd(), 0, 0, 0 );

// shows Unicode characters as ?
CreateWindow( "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 50, 20, GetSafeHwnd(), 0, 0, 0 );
```

You could create all edit boxes manually in `OnInitDialog` function of dialog box. And later subclass them to custom CMyEdit class with Unicode support.

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace these edit boxes with rich edit controls? Then you could enter international characters even in a non-Unicode build; internally, they would be rtf-encoded, but then when you stream the text out from the control, you can use the SF_UNICODE format to get the Unicode representation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - you could try turning on UNICODE for your build and use ANSI calls where you need to (eg. CStringA).

(*I understand that this may not be an option for you, but thought it worth pointing out that you could tackle this problem the other way round*)

Comment: I can't to that in this case.  There would be tens of thousands of calls to hunt down and convert.